# Kotlin kovenant succesUi on wrong thread?

Tags: kotlin

I have a strange problem with Kovenant. Either I don't understand something o there's some bug. Below code is a simple `task { } successUi { }` for Android. Yet `succesUi` generates  `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`, when cheking thread name it is:`kovenant-callback-2`, not main thread `iv` is `ImageView`.

```
    val promesa1 = task {
        val nazwa = Thread.currentThread().name
        print(nazwa)
    } successUi {
        val nazwa = Thread.currentThread().name
        print(nazwa)

        try {
            iv!!.setImageBitmap(null)
        } catch (ex : Exception) {
            print("Mamy:"+ex.toString())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essential that you call `startKovenant()` (and `stopKovenant()`) on your MainActivity. This will setup Kovenant for use with Android by keeping threads alive and attaching the proper Dispatchers to the UI callbacks.

So something like:

```
public class MainActivity : ... {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(...)

        // Configure Kovenant with standard dispatchers
        startKovenant()

    }

    ...

    override fun onDestroy() {
        stopKovenant()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

More on this topic can be found in the [Android configuration documentation](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/android/config/)

Comment: Off topic, but maybe you can answer it quickly here... What happened to numberOfThreads in buildDispatcher? Seems it doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: It has been renamed to 'concurrentTasks' for the sake of being language runtime agnostic.

Comment: @MPlatvoet would I have to re-configure kovenant with startKovenant() in every activity this way? Is doing this in the Application class only a bad idea? Thanks

Comment: You want to do this only once per application startup as this initialises the thread pools. So every place where you can guarantee this happens only once is a good place. You don't need to do this in every activity.